# Extracting a string located before a keyword

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I am new to Wolfram and i would like to extract a few words from a website based on locating a key string.

Specifically, i am trying to access the website:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2178/000000217818000009/a2017form10-k.htm
and locate the string "Address of Principal Executive Offices" and then scrape the address located right before the string "Address of Principal Executive offices".

I have run the following codes:

```
data = Import["https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2178/000000217818000009/a2017form10-k.htm", "Plaintext"]
```

this line above imports the link above.

```
keystring = StringPosition[data, {"Address of Principal Executive Offices"}]
```

This code above locates the string position at {{746, 783}}

How do I extract 10 words located right before the initial position of {{746}} so I could scrape the actual address and save that to Excel?

May i also ask that if i have a batch of websites saved on a .csv file, how i would apply "StringCases[plainText,
"(I.R.S. Employer Identification No.)\n\n" ~~ a___ ~~
"\n\n(Address of Principal Executive Offices)" :> a];"
to all of them?

For now, i have the following codes:

```
dataset = Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "linksto10k11.csv"}],"Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1];
dataWithProxyStatementURL = dataset[All, 13];
```

Above codes import the csv file i have with links to 10-K websites. Then, i run the following code to hopefully retrieve the actual address as above.

```
processProxyURL[proxyURL_] :=  Module[{plainText, address},plainText = Import[proxyURL, "Plaintext"];



address = StringCases[plainText,"(I.R.S. Employer Identification No.)\n\n" ~~ a___ ~~  "\n\n(Address of Principal Executive Offices)" :> a];    <|"Address" -> address|>];

Allrangeoutput =dataset[All, <|#,"All Range" -> processProxyURL[#["proxyStatementURL"]]|> &];
```

However, the above codes do not generate the actual address but only generate blanks - may i ask how i could update my codes accordingly so that i could retrieve the actual address?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

This will use the existing boilersplate on the form to "bracket" the data of interest and extract it:

```
data = Import[
   "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2178/000000217818000009/a2017form10-k.htm", "Plaintext"];

StringCases[
  data, 
  "(I.R.S. Employer Identification No.)\n\n" ~~ a___ ~~ 
   "\n\n(Address of Principal Executive Offices)" :> a
]

(* Out: {"17 SOUTH BRIAR HOLLOW LANE, SUITE 100, HOUSTON, TEXAS 77027"} *)
```

You can then use [`Export`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to export it to Excel.

This has the added advantage that you do not need to know how long the address is to extract it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your commenbt MarcoB!!!
I have a follow up question on using setting up a function for situations where i have a batch of links.

I have an .csv file with links to websites such as one above.
May i ask for your expertise on my current codes? I will revise my question above

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach: Import as `"Data"` (instead of `"Plaintext"`) and use `Position` + `Extract`:

```
dt = Import[
 "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2178/000000217818000009/a2017form10-k.htm", 
 "Data"];

Extract[dt, 
  Flatten @ Position[dt, "(Address of Principal Executive Offices) (Zip Code)"] - {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> "17 SOUTH BRIAR HOLLOW LANE, SUITE 100, HOUSTON, TEXAS 77027"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You may use "StringCases" like:

```
data = Import[
  "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2178/000000217818000009/\
a2017form10-k.htm", "Plaintext"]

addr = StringCases[data, 
   StartOfLine ~~ (WhitespaceCharacter | WordCharacter | ",") .. ~~ 
    EndOfLine ~~ WhitespaceCharacter .. ~~ 
    "(Address of Principal Executive Offices)"][[1]]
```

(* 17 SOUTH BRIAR HOLLOW LANE, SUITE 100, HOUSTON, TEXAS 77027
*)